# Laravel4 - handling date format between whole application and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

In laravel 4 i have lots of database fields that having date type and datetime . but i am need to show date format like dd/mm/yy H:i:s like any format and also have to handle date formation on insertion and update. Is they any way to get works in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, by creating `mutator` method in your model; for example, if you have a `Post` model and has a `date_of_birth` property and you want to set the date in `yyyy/mm/dd H:i:s` but user is probably providing the date in a different format. In this case crate a `mutator` method in the `Post` model like this:

```
public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
{
    // value will be the given date by user
    $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s',$value)->toDateString();
    $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = $dt;
}
```

To access the date just create an `accssor` method like:

```
public function getDateOfBirthAttribute()
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $this->date_of_birth);
}
```

Now the `date_of_birth` will be inserted using the format that you have used in the `mutator` method and when you'll show that date, it'll be displayed using the format that you have used in the `accessor` method. You may also check the [Date Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators).

Comment: i have `created_at` in each table , so it if i could handle in one place for all `created_at`, its easy . any idea to place any code in like global.php

Comment: Hey I found one idea to handle as `@WereWolf - The Alpha` said but i extend the models with the common model which is implemented above methods. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A must have package for dates is Carbon. Take a look at the documentation on GitHub: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: `Carbon` is available in `Laravel` by default ans every date (`created_at`, `deleted-at` are instance of `Carbon` by default).